# € Symbol from commandline (Arguments)

Tags: eiffel

I have a simple euro_to_dm command line program written but the "€" symbol doesn't work. The example change every time "dm to euro" but not "€ to dm". Sorry for my English.

Ubuntu 19.4 ise-eiffel AND liberty-eiffel

```
class EURO

inherit ARGUMENTS_32

create {ANY}
   make

feature {ANY}

   make
      do
         works_not
      end

   works_not
      local ok: BOOLEAN
      do
         print ("%N%NAnzahl Argumente : " + argument_count.out + "%N")
         print ("%NArgument -> Programmname    : " + argument(0))
         print ("%NArgument -> Wert            : " + argument(1))
         print ("%NArgument -> Währung         : " + argument(2) + "%N")

         ok := argument(2).is_equal("€")     
         print ("%NArgument(2) ist Euro ?  " + ok.out + "%N%N")

         print ("don't work")
         io.put_new_line

         if argument(2).is_equal("€") then
            euro_in_dm(argument(1).to_real)
         else
            dm_in_euro(argument(1).to_real)
         end
      end


feature {ANY}

   euro_in_dm (a: REAL)
      do
         io.put_string("%N Euro -> DM ")
         io.put_real(a * 1.95583)
         io.put_string("%N%N")
      end

   dm_in_euro (a: REAL)
      do
         io.put_string("%N DM -> Euro ")
         io.put_real(a / 1.95583)
         io.put_string("%N%N")
      end

end
```

Comment: Does     `if argument(2).is_equal("\0200")` work?

Comment: Don't work too. Liberty Eiffel works yesterday. ISE Eiffel today not.

Answer (score 0):

To create manifest Unicode string, you should use `{STRING_32} "€"`

To compare strings, you'd better use `same_string`, i.e
    `if s.same_string ({STRING_32} "€") then ...`

Note the syntax for manifest Unicode character using the hexadecimal value is `{CHARACTER_32} '%/0x20AC/'`

To output Unicode in console/terminal, it is better to use the `LOCALIZED_PRINTER` from the `encoding` library.

see https://www.eiffel.org/blog/jocelyn_fiat/lets_talk_about_the_encoding_library#Write_unicode_into_the_console

Comment: also be aware that  `"foo" + {STRING_32} "%/20AC/"`  will not do what you want, as the expression looks like `{STRING_8} + {STRING_32}.as_string_8`.   So you should really do `{STRING_32} "foo" + {STRING_32} "%/20AC/"` , or use a local  `s: STRING_32`, then use the `append` method.

Comment: lock at the next line - don’t work  :        if argument(2).same_string({STRING_32}"€") then
            euro_in_dm(argument(1).to_real)
        else
            dm_in_euro(argument(1).to_real)
        end
      end

Answer (score 0):

Here the program that works (this is in spanish). You should include the library *encoding* to your project. You cannot show the symbol € with **print**, you should use **localized_print**.

```
class
    EURO

inherit
    ARGUMENTS_32
    LOCALIZED_PRINTER

create
    make

feature {ANY}

   make
      do
         works_not
      end

   works_not
      local ok: BOOLEAN
      do
         print ("%N%NArgumentos                 : " + argument_count.out + "%N")
         print ("%NArgument -> Programa         : " + argument(0) + "%N")
         print ("%NArgument -> Valor            : " + argument(1) + "%N")
         localized_print ({STRING_32} "%NArgument -> Moneda           : " + argument(2) + {STRING_32} "%N")

         ok := argument(2).item(argument(2).lower).is_equal ('%/0x000020AC/')
         print ("%NArgument(2) ist Euro ?  " + ok.out + "%N%N")

         if ok then
            euro_in_dm(argument(1).to_real)
         else
            dm_in_euro(argument(1).to_real)
         end
      end


feature {ANY}

   euro_in_dm (a: REAL)
      do
         io.put_string("%N Euro -> DM ")
         io.put_real(a * 1.95583)
         io.put_string("%N%N")
      end

   dm_in_euro (a: REAL)
      do
         io.put_string("%N DM -> Euro ")
         io.put_real(a / 1.95583)
         io.put_string("%N%N")
      end
```

Comment: don't work too. Problem ise-eiffel don't found localized_printer. ise19_05

Comment: You should add the library "encoding" to your project. Click the icon "Add Library" at "Groups Tool" (the panel at right). Then search and select the "encoding" library and click the "Include" button.